# Get data from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-re

I have a string that contains player 1's nickname, player 1's profile link, player 2's nickname, player 2's profile link, weapons. I need to get this data from the line below

`[ex.endermen](profile_url1) got killed by [og.[(Z)]arcus(0.43k/d)](profile_url2) (FN Evolys, 56.83m)`

I need to get the data and output it in the format

`print(f"name1 = {name1}") print(f"name1_url = {name1_url}") print(f"name2 = {name2}") print(f"name2_url = {name2_url}")`

is there a way to get all the information correctly, provided that the string can change to this

`[ex.endermen](profile_url1) got killed by [og.[(Z)]arcus(0.43k/d)](profile_url2) (FN Evolys, 56.83m)`

or
`[ex.endermen](profile_url1) got killed by [platina](profile_url2) (FN Evolys, 56.83m)`
?

I tried to do it in multiple ways using regular expressions, but I got the same result which did not satisfy me

```
 name_weapon_pattern = r"\[(.*?)\].*\((.*?)\).*\((.*),.*\)"
 name_weapon_match = re.search(name_weapon_pattern, string)

 url_pattern = r"\((.*?)\)"
 url_match = re.findall(url_pattern, string)

 name1 = name_weapon_match.group(1)
 name1_url = name_weapon_match.group(2)
 name2 = name_weapon_match.group(3)
 name2_url = url_match[1]

 print(f"name1 = {name1}")
 print(f"name1_url = {name1_url}")
 print(f"name2 = {name2}")
 print(f"name2_url = {name2_url}")
```

result:

```
name1 = og.[(Z)
name1_url = name2_url
name2 = FN Evolys
name2_url = 0.43k/d
```

Comment: Rather than reinventing the wheel with regex, I'd suggest researching existing Python Markdown parsers, which will actually handle all the edge cases that a regex either won't handle, or would require unreadable hundred-plus character patterns to fully handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @shadowranger that regex is probably not the optimal tool for this use case. But anyway there is my solution using `named_groups`:

```py
import re

p = re.compile(r"\[(?P<name1>.*?)\]\((?P<name1_url>.*?)\).*?\[(?P<name2>.*?)\]\((?P<name2_url>.*?)\)\s\((?P<weapons>.*)\)$")

text = '[ex.endermen](profile_url1) got killed by [og.[(Z)]arcus(0.43k/d)](profile_url2) (FN Evolys, 56.83m)'

p.match(text).groupdict()

# outputs
# {'name1': 'ex.endermen',
#  'name1_url': 'profile_url1',
#  'name2': 'og.[(Z)]arcus(0.43k/d)',
#  'name2_url': 'profile_url2',
#  'weapons': 'FN Evolys, 56.83m'}

text = '[ex.endermen](profile_url1) got killed by [platina](profile_url2) (FN Evolys, 56.83m)'

p.match(text).groupdict()

# outputs
# {'name1': 'ex.endermen',
#  'name1_url': 'profile_url1',
#  'name2': 'platina',
#  'name2_url': 'profile_url2',
#  'weapons': 'FN Evolys, 56.83m'}

# you can access individual groups with
m = p.match(text)
m["name1"]
# > 'ex.endermen'
```

The problem with nested brackets can be solved using recursive pattern (which is not supported in `re`, you would need to use `regex`), but in this case we can find the `name2` by matching `](` characters. This obviously breaks when the name2 contains this sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import re

def extract_players(string):
  name_weapon_pattern  = r"\[(.*?)\].*\((.*?)\).*\[(.*?)\].*\((.*?)\).*\((.*?),.*?\)"
  name_weapon_match = re.search(name_weapon_pattern, string)
  name1 = name_weapon_match.group(1)
  name1_url = name_weapon_match.group(2)
  name2 = name_weapon_match.group(3)
  name2_url = name_weapon_match.group(4)
  return (name1, name1_url, name2, name2_url)

# Test the function with different strings
string_1 = "[ex.endermen](profile_url1) got killed by [og.[(Z)]arcus(0.43k/d)](profile_url2) (FN Evolys, 56.83m)"
string_2= "[ex.endermen](profile_url1) got killed by [platina](profile_url2) (FN Evolys, 56.83m)"
string_3 ="[ex.endermen](profile_url1) got killed by [og.[(Z)]arcus(0.43k/d)](profile_url2) (FN Evolys, 56.83m)"  

print(extract_players(string_1))
print(extract_players(string_2))
print(extract_players(string_3))
```

Output:

```
('ex.endermen', 'profile_url1', '(Z)', 'profile_url2')
('ex.endermen', 'profile_url1', 'platina', 'profile_url2')
('ex.endermen', 'profile_url1', '(Z)', 'profile_url2')
```

Comment: the result should be like this
('ex.endermen', 'profile_url1', 'og.[(Z)]arcus(0.43k/d)', 'profile_url2')